# Corda Enterprise throws "net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException" for custom schema while running the test cases

Tags: blockchain, corda

As per the Corda enterprise documentation, we have added the custom schema like below

```
fun setup() {
        network = MockNetwork(cordappPackages = listOf("com.xxx.service", "com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.zzzz", "com.xxx.kkk", "com.xxx.ttt", "com.xxx.yyyy.schema"))
}
```

Or

```
fun setup() {
        network = MockNetwork(listOf("com.xxx.service", "com.xxx.yyy", "com.xxx.zzzz", "com.xxx.kkk", "com.xxx.ttt", "com.xxx.yyyy.schema"))
}
```

While running the test cases we are facing the below issues,

```
[INFO] 12:11:35,213 [main] cordapp.CordappLoader.scanCordapp - Scanning CorDapp in file:/C:/Users/************/generated-test-cordapps/com.xxx.service-c7ab4ac5-fd21-40ae-86e6-18cc219b3179.jar
[INFO] 12:11:35,862 [main] hikari.HikariDataSource.<init> - HikariPool-1 - Started.
[WARN] 12:11:37,726 [main] persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration - No migration defined for schema: com.xxx.yyy.schema.yyyy v1
[WARN] 12:11:37,733 [main] persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration - No migration defined for schema: com.xxx.yyy.schema.xxxStateSchema v1
[INFO] 12:11:40,127 [main] persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration - defaultSchemaName=PUBLIC



 net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: 
                    Please register the entity 'com.xxx.yyyy.schema.XXXXSchemaV1$XXXX'
                    See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration for more information
```

Help is needed.

Comment: Can you post your schema definition here as well?

Answer (score 0):

In Corda Enterprise a schema class need to have corresponding Liquibase migration script with tables definition. This script will create backing table.
The error

```
persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration - No migration defined for schema: com.xxx.yyy.schema.yyyy v1*
```

suggested this, but you might also misconfigured the script file name.
If the schema class doesn't override *migrationResource* field then the file name with Liquibase schema needs to follow the pattern upper case is change to lower case preceding by hyphen e.g. for class

*com.example.MyMappedSchema*

the relevant script file is expected to be

*my-mapped-schema.changelog-master.XXX*, where XXX can be *xml*, *sql*, *yml* or *json*

The file needs to be place in *resources/migration* source folder to be copied in Cordapp JAR (or to be found for testing).
If your schema class have *migrationResource* then the Liquibase scrip still needs to be under *resources/migration* folder.